# Laravel redirects to a route but then apache gives 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, laravel

I have a site that is working on the same server in a different url (staging), but now I've deployed the site and the base url ("/") is redirected to the login url (so laravel is sort of working), but then I get a 404 error from apache.

If I use sub.domain.com/index.php/route, it works, but if I use sub.domain.com/route redirects to the login route and gives a 404 error.

I also changed the routes.php to return the login view in the route "/" and it show the login form correctly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After adding

```
AllowOverride All
```

to the vhost configuration, got it working. Probably the default configuration wasn't allowing the redirects?

Here's my final (and working) vhost configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/sitefolder/public
 ServerName site.domain.com
 <Directory /var/www/sitefolder/public>
  AllowOverride All
  allow from all
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yep. Whats happening here is that theres a .htaccess in /public/ that fixes the urls to hide the index.php. However for this to run it needs AllowOverride All, as .htaccess is about issuing further apache server config not specified in the /etc/apache (or wherever your distro puts it) cluster of configs

Answer (score 32):

The problem might come from a module in your Apache server called rewrite module.
in windows you can just uncomment this line from your httpd.conf

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and enabled it using

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Try these with an Apache restart.
It might work for you as well.

Comment: Tnx a lot buddy. You are the best :*

Comment: Just saved me here, although I got some errors, but my problems all got solved, Thanks

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` solves the problem for url path showing not found on apache. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

**For `VirtualHost`**

Only add these lines into `httpd.conf` of your apache:

```
<Directory /var/www/sitefolder/public>
  AllowOverride All
  allow from all
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Or you can replace the first line with:

```
<Directory />
```

And if all doesn't work, you can try:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```