# Error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Trying to recover laravel application. Can't access any route, everywhere error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

My web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@getIndex');

Route::get('/posts', 'IndexController@getPosts');

Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'IndexController@getPost');

Route::get('/posts/category/{id}', 'IndexController@getPostCategory');

Route::get('/reviews', 'IndexController@getReviews');

Route::get('/pages/{id}', 'IndexController@getPage');

Route::get('/contacts', 'IndexController@getContacts');

Route::post('/request', 'IndexController@postRequest');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::resource('settings', 'SettingController');

    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');

    Route::resource('data', 'DataController');

    Route::resource('reviews', 'ReviewController');

    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');

    Route::resource('pages', 'PageController');
});
```

All controllers and views exist. Apache DocumentRoot is /public/ directory. Standard laravel .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I would have more information but I will do my best.

Laravel needs 2 things from `apache` to start working

1. rewrite enabled `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
2. `.htaccess` enabled

> You can do it by editing `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
>   and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.
>   This should be done for `/var/www` (the default DocumentRoot for apache)

After doing this use `php artisan serve` to start a PHP server.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer, What information do you need? And about rewrite and .htaccess, everything enabled

Comment: I don't thinks so just have a check also this 404 is of laravel so it is responding
you can `dd()` in `/` route to make sure and do the same in some other route

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757749/laravel-redirects-to-a-route-but-then-apache-gives-404-error see this to know more

Comment: Understood what's the problem. In my controller "IndexController" I have a method "getIndex", there settings, data and other and return view, but after this code $settings = Setting::findOrFail(1); I even don't see dd(). Some kind problem exatcly with it.

Comment: It turns out, that the problem is completely different. There wasn't data in the settings table, so findOfFail thew exception. But I think if the problem was with web server, you would help me with your answer)